# Text spacing/padding within H1 tag is inconsistent across browsers

Tags: html, padding, spacing

I'm creating a personal website using HTML5 and CSS3. In the attached image, you can quickly see what the problem is.
I can't find the reason for it since the code seems valid. I'm thinking it might have something to do with browser quirks but I just don't know which.

I'm not so worried about Opera not rendering the correct font-face, as much as I am with the inconsistent letter spacing or padding. Firefox is the worst of all.

[image: Inconsistent letter spacing in H1 tag]

Here is the HTML code (by the way, I'm using the 960 grid system):

```
<div id=body-wrap class="container_12">
<header class="container_12">
    <hgroup>
        <div class="grid_9">
            <h1>THIS IS A TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <div id=lang class="grid_3">
            <a href=#>
                <img src=esp_64.png alt="Bandera de España">
            </a>
            <a href=#>
                <img src=cat_64.png alt="Senyera Catalana">
            </a>
            <a href=#>
                <img src=eng_64.png alt="British Union Jack">
            </a>
        </div>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

Here is relevant CSS for the HTML above:

```
h1 { font-size: 55px }
header { padding: 10px 0 }
header div h1 {
    font-family: "PTSansBold", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0a7bb4;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    height: 70px
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is gecko-only related you could try to make some adjustment with more specific css properties like [font-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size-adjust) or [font-stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-stretch) (available from Firefox 9.0)

if this don't solve, try to also set `letter-spacing: 0` only for firefox (e.g. with some media query that only gecko understands). This should be enough to make heading almost wide the same and will be supported even from older firefox version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but no luck. `font-stretch` doesn't work with font-faces and in fact, if I remove my font-faces and use default fonts, the problem is gone! Quite **strange**. It seems the problem is the correct rendering of the new fonts (I've tried several and allways happens, so it's not just one).